# Databases for pdf tables

Tags: data.gov

Are there databases for the open data Dietary Reference Intake PDFs?

I found the PDFs for the DRI tables but wish to have the format as a database table for purposes of creating a computer app.

The PDFs can be found [here](http://iom.nationalacademies.org/~/media/Files/Activity%20Files/Nutrition/DRIs/5_Summary%20Table%20Tables%201-4.pdf)

Comment: you can create them; there are plenty of open source pdf scraping tools you can utilize to achieve this. i use tabula http://tabula.technology/